# Как двум картинкам обменяться адресами src?

Tags: javascript

Привет.
Есть 2 картинки доступны как document.getElementById(dropTarget) и element.
Как первой картинке присвоить src второй ,а второй -первой.

```
document.getElementById(dropTarget).src=element.src;
```

Но как теперь второй поставить адрес который был до этого в первой?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var t=document.getElementById(dropTarget).src;
document.getElementById(dropTarget).src=element.src;
element.src=t;
```

Comment: нет!2 картинки будут иметь одинаковое изображение....Спасибо за старания

Comment: @koza4ok, извините, поспешил. Попробуйте исправленый вариант.

Comment: УРА!!!!!СПАСИБО!!!!!Огромное тебе спасибо

Answer (score 4):

Алгоритм обмена значений двух переменных:

```
var a = "this";
var b = "that";
var c = a;
a = b;
b = c;
```

Реализацию Вы сами можете написать.

Comment: спасибо.Будем такую технологию знать

Comment: @koza4ok, извините, но как Вы вообще программируете? 

Вы что, книжек по программированию (BASIC, Pascal, C/C++, Java ..., а вообще-то любой язык общего назначения) не читали? Ни разу ни одной сортировки не написали?

Comment: а как бы реализовали Вы, @avp ?

Comment: @Rules - ты не понял :)

Я тоже сразу не так понял, @avp адресовал эту речь автору вопроса, а не автору ответа

Comment: @Rules, естественно, комментарий о книжках к автору вопроса (там и ник **автора вопроса**). Ответ очевидно правильный.